# What is the RTF syntax for a hyperlink to a Word document?

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, rtf

I know the syntax for a hyperlink to an external site :

```
{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com/"}{\fldrslt http://www.google.com}}
```

but not to an existing word document.

Comment: Create a Word document with a hyperlink to a location in the document. Save it as RTF. Open the file in a text editor and look at the syntax.

Comment: Well, The RTF specifications lack some of the semantic definitions necessary to read, write and modify documents. Novell alleged that Microsoft's practices were anticompetitive in its antitrust complaint against Microsoft. Whenever you edit semantically created document with office word and save, it messes up entirely. So RTF generated with microsoft word will not solve your problem. Please try another approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "D:\\Folder\\File.doc"}}{\fldrslt{\ul <link text>}
```